# Multiple table JOIN Row count

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, I have a slightly complicated MySQL query

```
SELECT
  childcare_attendance.supplier_id,
  suppliers.name As `Childcare Provider`,
  Count(families.ufi) As Attended,
  families.ufi
FROM
  childcare_attendance
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  suppliers ON suppliers.id = childcare_attendance.supplier_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  clients ON childcare_attendance.client_id = clients.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  families ON clients.family_id = families.id
WHERE
  childcare_attendance.trashed <> 1
GROUP BY
  childcare_attendance.supplier_id, families.ufi
```

My issue is I want to create a report that lists the number of unique families that are attending each of the childcare places. I assumed that the above query would perform the task, although the childcare providers are showing multiple times and I am unsure why.

**EDIT**

Here is a SQL Fiddle without data (I will work on getting some test data in there)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7ef8e8

Comment: You have another problem, namely that you are selecting the `suppliers.name` column without including it in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Of course it allows this, but it might not be giving him the result he wants.  So I think he might want to fix this.

Comment: Can you please provide sample data and desired results?  If you're getting duplicate providers returned (assuming that's the `supplier_id`), do they all have a different `ufi`?

Comment: @sgeddes the `childcare_attendance` table stores records for the attendance, in that table there are multiple records that can have the same `client_id` which is the unique identifier for the relationship between the tables `childcare_attendance` and `clients`

I will send a link to SQLFiddle shortly, although it will not have any data as it is confidential